# Compiletime narrowing wchar to char

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, compile-time

In my compile time function I'd like to work with strings. BOTH ANSI and WIDE ones. So, I added a quick template to handle both. This is all easy-peasy, but I've got a special function which calculates security checksum on strings. This works on a byte array and it would take quite huge effort to rewrite to work on  variable buffer size, so I thought I will just simply narrow the wchar down to char and let my function work on it. By default it doesn't work as I thought it should be.

Sample code to reproduce my problem:
https://godbolt.org/z/ya2zq7

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr void hack(const char* const from, const size_t fromLen, char* const to)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fromLen; i++)
    {
        to[i] = from[i] + 1;
    }
}

template <typename U, std::size_t LENGTH>
class EncryptedStorage
{
    U m_data[LENGTH]{};

public:
    constexpr EncryptedStorage(const U* input)
    {
        hack(static_cast<const char* const>(input), LENGTH * sizeof(U), static_cast<char* const>(m_data));
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Test with CHAR
    constexpr char test[] = "Hello World";
    constexpr size_t size = sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]);
    constexpr auto encrypted = EncryptedStorage<char, size>(test);

    // test with WCHAR
    constexpr wchar_t wtest[] = L"Hello World";
    constexpr size_t wsize = sizeof(wtest) / sizeof(wtest[0]);
    constexpr auto wencrypted = EncryptedStorage<wchar_t, wsize>(wtest);
}
```

If you comment the wide strings it will compile perfectly. Is it possible to do what I want, or I should really really rework all my algorithm to work on variable size?

Comment: Why not treat the `wchar_t` string as an array of bytes, and calculate the checksum for that?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, but that would require narrowing somewhere sooner or later. I mean once you have to cast wchar* to char* according to my knowledge.

Comment: No narrowing needed, unless you want to convert the `wchar_t` ***characters*** to `char`. Simply cast to `const char*` and you have a pointer to a buffer of bytes.

Comment: I might be wrong but in my example code I'm exactly trying to do that and fails to compile. Could you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem in your code is that you can't use `static_cast` to covert between pointers to different data types - when those types are *unrelated*, as `char` and `wchar_t` are; for this, you need a `reinterpret_cast` or a `C`-style cast:

```cpp
constexpr EncryptedStorage(const U* input)
{
    hack(reinterpret_cast<const char* const>(input), LENGTH * sizeof(U), reinterpret_cast<char* const>(m_data));
}
```

However, once you have such a cast, your `EncyptedStorage` function can no longer be evaluated at compile time, so two of the`constexpr` declarations in your `main` will fail, and you will have to just use `const` instead:

```cpp
const auto encrypted = EncryptedStorage<char, size>(test);
const auto wencrypted = EncryptedStorage<wchar_t, wsize>(wtest); // Can't use constexpr
```

EDIT:
Another way (perhaps nicer) is to use *function-style* casts:

```cpp
using pcchar = const char* const;
using pchar = char* const;
constexpr EncryptedStorage(const U* input)
{
    hack(pcchar(input), LENGTH * sizeof(U), pchar(m_data));
}
```

With this, you can use `constexpr` for `encrypted` but not for `wencrypted`!

Comment: I'd like to do it in compile time, so simply removing constexpr is not an option for me.